# Validate individual hardware components process

Tags: tpm

UFEI Secure Boot does not validate individual hardware components (SSD/hard drive, networking chips/card, video card, etc.) that can get infected.

Is there anything currently available that's able to do that? If there isn't how would you implement it yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing that can fully validate all components which exist in a general use system.

That is because components such as hard drives and video cards have their own firmware which they run. This firmware is the target of the attack, and there is no standard verification which all components in order to validate their state.

Chromium and the line of Chromebooks are one step better than secure boot. They offer something called verified boot which does a great job of detecting tampering.

https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/chromiumos-design-docs/verified-boot

The downside is how limited Chromebooks are as general purpose computers.

Comment: Using an encrypted disk with only the bootloader unencrypted (and verified with SRTM using the TPM) would take the disks out of the TCB. Even better if authenticated encryption were used, or at least a non-malleable wide-block cipher mode like EME2 or XCB.